# Error 401 (no autorizado) al realizar una llamada Ajax - ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net

No tengo mucha experiencia en cuestión de ajax y tengo un problema al realizar una llamada ajax en ASP.NET, mi problema es que cuando intento realizar la llamada, recibo el error **401 (no autorizado)**, el código que tengo para el llamado ajax es:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Prueba.aspx/Test",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Correcto")
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
    }
});
```

En el codebehind el código es el siguiente:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Test()
{
    return "";
}
```

¿Alguien sabrá por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: ¿De casualidad te dice algo referido al "CORS"?

Comment: Indica por favor el **CodeBehind** de tu página `Prueba.aspx` con el método `Test`.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta ya agregué lo que tengo en el CodeBehind

Comment: @fredyfx en el errorThrown solo me muestra **Unauthorized**